# Button becomes unclickable on changing background color

Tags: html, css, button, background, disable

Whenever i change the background color of a button in CSS, it becomes unclickable. Same happens if i remove button border in css

HTML

```
<div class="row">
                    <button onclick="click('7')" class="btn">7</button>
                    <button onclick="click('8')" class="btn">8</button>
                    <button onclick="click('9')" class="btn">9</button>
                    <button onclick="click('/')" class="btn">/</button>
                </div>
```

CSS

```
.btn{
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    margin-left: 30px;
    margin-top: 25px;
    background: beige;   
   }
```

Comment: what does your `click` function do and where is it?

Comment: function click(val)
    {
        document.getElementById("screen").value+=val
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Certainly in Google Chrome using `click` as the function name was causing an issue - changing that to `clicker`, for instance, seems to alleviate that issue and it works as expected.

```js
function clicker(val) {
  document.getElementById("screen").value += val 
}
```

```css
.btn {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  margin-left: 30px;
  margin-top: 25px;
  background: beige;
  cursor:pointer;
}
.btn:hover{
  background:rgba(0,100,0,0.25)
}

#screen{
  width:25rem;
  height:2rem;
  border:2px solid black;
  margin:2rem 0;
  background: beige;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <button onclick="clicker('7')" class="btn">7</button>
  <button onclick="clicker('8')" class="btn">8</button>
  <button onclick="clicker('9')" class="btn">9</button>
  <button onclick="clicker('/')" class="btn">/</button>
</div>

<input type='text' id='screen' />
```

An alternative using a delegated event listener

```js
document.querySelector('.row').addEventListener('click',e=>{
  document.querySelector('#screen').value+=e.target.textContent
})
```

```css
.btn {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  margin-left: 30px;
  margin-top: 25px;
  background: beige;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.btn:hover {
  background: rgba(0, 100, 0, 0.25)
}

#screen {
  width: 25rem;
  height: 2rem;
  border: 2px solid black;
  margin: 2rem 0;
  background: beige;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <button class="btn">7</button>
  <button class="btn">8</button>
  <button class="btn">9</button>
  <button class="btn">/</button>
</div>
<input type='text' id='screen' />
```

Answer (score 0):

try background-color

and it is still clickable, I think you are missing the :hover s

```css
.btn{
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    margin-left: 30px;
    margin-top: 25px;
    background-color: beige;   
   }
.btn:hover {
  background-color:gray;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
                    <button onclick="click('7')" class="btn">7</button>
                    <button onclick="click('8')" class="btn">8</button>
                    <button onclick="click('9')" class="btn">9</button>
                    <button onclick="click('/')" class="btn">/</button>
                </div>
```